gmp_mod() error when running Laravel tests in Github actions
I'm trying to run my Laravel 11 test quite within Github actions. I've set up my tests workflow and have a test suite that makes HTTP requests that work when running locally both in sqlite and mysql. In production, when dumping the response of one of my tests, I get this error:

gmp_mod(): Argument #1 ($num1) must be of type GMP|string|int, Illuminate\Support\Stringable given

To me this sounds like an issue with my workflow config so just need someone to point out what I'm missing:
name: tests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - v2-dev
  pull_request:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04

    strategy:
      fail-fast: true
      matrix:
        php: [8.3]
        laravel: [11]
        exclude:
          - php: 8.3
            laravel: 11

    name: PHP ${{ matrix.php }} - Laravel ${{ matrix.laravel }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: ${{ matrix.php }}
          extensions: dom, curl, libxml, mbstring, zip, bcmath
          ini-values: error_reporting=E_ALL
          tools: composer:v2
          coverage: none

      - name: Copy .env
        run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction --no-progress

      - name: Create SQLite database file
        run: |
          if [ ! -f database/database.sqlite ]; then
            touch database/database.sqlite
          fi

      - name: Run migrations
        run: php artisan migrate
        env:
          DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
          DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite

      - name: Execute tests
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit
        env:
          DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
          DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite


The offending test:
public function test_retrieve_application_with_body_is_successful(): void
{
    $application = ApplicationEntry::factory()->make();

    $response = $this->post('/api/v2/applications', [
        'product_type' => 'tests',
        'data' => (new Honeycomb())->setApplication(
            collect($application?->data)->toArray()
        )->getMappedApplication()
    ]);

    $response->dump();

    $response = $this->get('/api/v2/applications/'.(string) Arr::get($response, 'model.hash', 'unknown'));

    $response->assertSuccessful()
        ->assertJsonStructure([
            'model',
            'metadata',
        ]);
}

The output from Github actions


Do you have a backtrace of the error?

Nope, it's Github actions

The error Argument #1 ($num1) must be of type GMP|string|int, ... given should be followed by , called in ... on line ... plus a backtrace. I'm afraid, there is not enough information in your question. Maybe try to re-read the logs, try to run phpunit with --display-warnings --fail-on-warning. The only thing I can tell you with a high level of certainty is that is likely an effect of declare(strict_types=1);. If you remove it from the test file and the class(es) being tested, the error should go away.

The error doesn't happen locally, as I say, is this related to a PHP package in Github actions potentially?

I don't think it's related to GitHub actions. You might not get the error locally if you are using a different environment (Docker images, php version etc.)

@RuslanOsmanov As I mentioned, this works completely fine locally. I've updated the description with the output from Github actions

You didn’t mention how you run it locally. Do you locally run the same GH actions configuration (the same docker images etc)? If you do, then it would be helpful to share the shell commands used
